# How do I listen for packets with Racket?

Tags: port, racket, packet, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am attempting to use Racket to listen for packets moving through port 80 on my machine. However, I seem to be running into a wall with either my understanding of how a packet sniffer works, my understanding of how Racket works, or both.

Here is my code (most of it comes from [Racket's Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_features)).

```
#lang racket

(require racket/tcp)

(define listener (tcp-listen 80))

(define (echo-server)
  (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
  (thread (lambda () (copy-port in out) 
                     (print (read in)) 
                     (close-output-port out)))
  (echo-server))

(echo-server)
```

When I connect to `localhost:80` I get some feedback - but when I try to use my web browsers I can't get anything to print. How do I amend this code so that it will listen for packets coming in and going out from web requests?

Comment: By writing moving through i get the impression you want to intercept communication to port 80 while your code only works for urls representing the machine it runs on, like http://localhost/blabla and not as a sniffer.  If you are just looking for a sniffer I suggest wireshark.

Comment: I believe you want to implement a _proxy server_ not an echo server: a process that stands in the middle of an HTTP connection and "sees" all incoming/outgoing traffic while allowing a normal communication.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yes, I believe that's what I am looking for - could you elaborate in an answer the difference between what I have and a proxy server (briefly, if I ask too much)?

Comment: @sdasdadas look for examples of proxy servers. Essentially, it's a process that sits in-between, receives a request from the client, redirects it to the real target, receives the target's response and forwards it to the client ... and does whatever it wants with the request/response that went across it

Comment: The `packet-socket` library (last updated 2017) allows access to raw ethernet frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I seem to be running into a wall with either my understanding of how a packet sniffer works

Yes.  A packet sniffer does *not* use regular sockets; it uses whatever mechanisms are available to passively watch packets received by or sent on a network interface.  If you just want to *watch* HTTP traffic on port 80, without *responding* to that traffic or *altering* that traffic, you will need to use something such as libpcap/WinPcap, which use the appropriate mechanism on your OS for passively watching packets.  See, for example, the [SPeaCap library for Racket](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/display.ss?package=SPeaCAP.plt&owner=evanfarrer).

Note, however, that if you passively sniff traffic, what you'll see are raw link-layer packets; to extract TCP content from them, you'll have to parse the link-layer header, IP header, and TCP header in order to find the contents.  I will leave it up to you to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I don't mind getting in between the packets (like a man in the middle attack?) - but I was ignorant as to if it was possible to sit between my Chrome client and port 80 (and intercept, analyze, and pass forward the packets going from Chrome to some web server). Can this easily be done? Or is this use case exactly why packet sniffing exists?

Comment: Packet sniffing involves intercepting and analyzing; it doesn't involve passing forward, any more than, for example, wiretapping a telephone involves hearing what one person said and repeating it to the other person so they hear it.  Another alternative is to write a Web proxy program that passes all traffic through, in both directions, and also does its own analysis of the traffic.  To use *that*, however, you'd have to configure Chrome to go through your application as a proxy server.  I will leave it up to you to figure out how to do that.

Comment: `SPeaCap` is very outdated. The `packet-socket` library (last updated 2017) allows access to raw ethernet frames.

Answer (score 0):

Your TCP server is just acting as an echo server, which means that it's not conforming to [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). Your browser is expecting a valid HTTP response, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

Racket has libraries for all sorts of things. A quick search of the documentation turned up this: [Web Server: HTTP Server](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/)

Comment: I may be off base, but I'm not too interested in the web server side of things. I just want to grab the headers of network data coming through port 80. Even if my browser expects an HTTP response, won't I still intercept the request going out?

Answer (score 0):

The `packet-socket` library (last updated 2017) allows access to raw ethernet frames. [packet-socket](https://pkgs.racket-lang.org/package/packet-socket) on pkgd